# Do verbs in interrogative sentences containing 'or' agree with the subject immediately after them?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Either my father or my brothers have paid for lunch.

> Either my brothers or my father has paid for lunch.

I think both of these sentences are correct because the verb is supposed to agree with the subject following the 'or' (please correct me if I am wrong)

But what about these two questions:

> Has my father or my brothers paid for lunch?

> Have my brothers or my father paid for lunch?

Are these correct? Am I correct to assume that the *'to have verb'* agrees with the subject immediately following it in these situations?

Comment: Both of your sentences are grammatically correct if observed as a noun phrase. If you wanted to emphasize the usage of coordination : *"or"*, you would use the expression *"either ... or ..."*. But if a person is not sure who has paid or has yet to pay the check, he would probably answer *"Either/ **Neither** your father or/ **nor** brothers have paid for lunch"*.

Comment: It is a very complex issue of the writing style, the so called **agreement**. Some possible proving of the grammatical construction that should be applied here vast and complex. It is better to transform the syntax in such cases on practice, for example, *Has my father paid for lunch, or it has been my brothers who paid actually?* Depending on dialects, style and discourse, both your sentences could be taken as right sentences.

Comment: @kngram Shouldn't it be 'or has it been my brothers' ? Just making sure.

Comment: No. Better to do as I have said. But, be attentive, this is the question of the style. So your teacher is the most authoritative figure to tell you how to do it right.